# Trying to run Swift Vapor on Bluemix - 404 Not Found: Requested route does not exist

Tags: swift, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, vapor

**I'm trying to figure out how to deploy in IBM Bluemix a Cloudfoundry app that uses Vapor framework.**

IBM is providing facilities and guidance for using his platform for developing server side Swift apps with his framework, Kitura. I think as a Cloudfoundry provider, with the proper Swift buildpack, we must be able to deploy generic server side Swift code.

Finally, while learning bits of CF, I reached the point that with the CloudFoundry CLI:

1. I'm connecting to the Bluemix API endpoint (api .eu-gb .bluemix .net)
2. Login ok (after expanding the timeout setting env. var CF_DIAL_TIMEOUT to 20)
3. Making a "cf push". It creates the app and uploads and compiles everything.
4. The app state is "running".

But when I load the page (https://sommobilitatcore.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/) I get:

```
404 Not Found: Requested route ('sommobilitatcore.eu-gb.mybluemix.net') does not exist.
```

**Can anyone help me on that? Thanks!**

Some context:

The manifest.yml:

```
applications:
- path: .
  memory: 256M
  instances: 1
  name: SomMobilitatCore
  disk_quota: 1024M
  buildpack: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/swift-buildpack.git
```

The Procfile

```
web: App
```

(main.swift is in Source/App/)

No port is configured in Vapor Config files, then Vapor is trying to listen to port 80:

```
import Vapor
import HTTP

let drop = Droplet()

let _ = drop.config["app", "key"]?.string ?? ""

drop.get("/") { request in
    return try drop.view.make("welcome.html")
}

(...)

let port = drop.config["app", "port"]?.int ?? 80

// Print what link to visit for default port
drop.serve()
```

**UPDATE:**

Finally get it working without Procfile, the manifest.yml

```
- path: .
  instances: 1
  memory: 256M
  disk_quota: 1024M
  name: SomMobilitat4
  command: App --env=production --workdir="./"
  buildpack: swift_buildpack
```

And the /Config/production/servers.json :

```
{
    "production": {
        "port": "$PORT"
    }
}
```

I neither specify the port variable in the main.swift file. With the updated Vapor version:

```
import Vapor
import HTTP

let drop = Droplet()

drop.get("/") { request in
    return "hello vapor in bluemix cloudfoundry"
}


drop.run()
```

If you are new to Cloudfoundry or IBM Bluemix, this is a way to work:

1. You signup in a Cloudfoundry provider (ex: bluemix)
2. You have you Vapor project locally.
3. Add to it a .cfignore file with this short line: Packages/
   to avoid uploading Packages to the server.
4. Add to it the mentioned manifest.yml file.
5. Download and install the Cloudfoundry CLI: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/

   With the CLI:
6. cf api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
7. cf login
8. cf push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a Vapor app on Bluemix:

1. Add `Config` directory with `servers.json` (use exactly these names). `servers.json` should contain the following:

   ```
       {
           "myserver": {
               "port": "$PORT"
           }
       }
   ```

It will instruct Vapor to start a server named `myserver` on the port taken from `$PORT` environment variable used by Bluemix.

2. In your `Procfile`, add `--workDir=.` parameter, so it would contain:

   ```
   web: App --workDir=.
   ```

   It will instruct Vapor to look for `Config` directory in the current directory during run time.

Comment: I finally get it working, but without de Procfile, I set the command in the manifest.yml

Comment: - path: .
       memory: 256M
       instances: 1
      name: Appname
       command: App --env=production --workdir="./"
     disk_quota: 1024M
     buildpack: swift_buildpack

Comment: It should work both ways - either with Procfile or with command in the manifest.yml.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with Swift and Vapor, but for any cloud foundry application you have to use the port from the VCAP_APPLICATION environment variable.

Bluemix created a useful package for Swift that you can get this port number.

In your Package.swift file add the following line:

```
.Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-cfenv.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 7)
```

Then you can use something like this to get the correct port number to start your application:

```
import CloudFoundryEnv

...

let appEnv: AppEnv
appEnv = try CloudFoundryEnv.getAppEnv()
let port = appEnv.port
```

You can check Bluemix Swift start code here for more details:

https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/Kitura-Starter

Comment: Hi Alex, I think you are right and seems a port configuration problem. I tried this way but then I get:

Comment: DEA/130Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections

Comment: I have also tried to set VCAP_APPLICATION through Vapor configuration files: but fails the same way.

Comment: Hi Daniel, as Alex suggested, you may want to look at https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/Kitura-Starter. The main thing you'll need is a manifest.yml file in your repo. If you include the command attribute in your manifest.yml file, then you won't need a Procfile. You may also want to go over the README file for the buildpack: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/swift-buildpack. You may also want to check out this repo: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-cfenv. Is your Vapor-based application on GitHub? If so, we could take a look at it.

Comment: For some, I think, unrelated problem I didn't get it work in that way. Finally it worked to me without the need of this package. But it's nice to know about it. Vapor can get the enviorent $PORT variable in its configuration files and it worked. Thanks.